# Java Web Start is unable to automatically download and install the requested version

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have java 1.6 update 30 installed on my desktop.

The jnlp specifies that the minimum java version is Java 1.7.

However I get this error

> Java Web Start Error:
>   
>   The application has requested a version of the JRE (version 1.7+) that currently is not locally installed. Java Web Start is unable to
>
> automatically download and install the requested version. This JRE
>   must be installed manually.

**UPDATE:**

What does this error mean?
How can I force or suggest a java 7 install?

It would be fine if the user was redirected to http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

I know that that this can be achieved with `deployJava.js`

Thanks!

Comment: ..do you have a question?

Comment: ...do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add following line to your JNLP file

`<java  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.7+" >`

1. Modify your landing page with following code

add the java script in header

`<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>`

in your html document body

`<p><script> var url="url of your jnlp file ";
deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url,'1.7.0');</script></p>`

for more information please look at [Deploy Rich Internet Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html)

I hope this will fix your issue

Comment: The linked-to documentation is for Java 6, which is generally not supported any more. Updated documentation for Java 8 can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/ria_development.html#JSDPG1024