# Auto installation of the required JRE version is not working with Java Web Start

Tags: java, java-web-start

I want to run my app only with particular JRE 1.7 version. If the client has lower versions of JRE installed,  I want to auto-install the JRE 1.7 before launching the app via JNLP file.

I have the following line in my JNLP file ...

> j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se

But, when I launch the application with JRE6, I am getting the error ...
"The application has requested a version of the JRE (version 1.7+) that currently is not locally installed. Java Web Start is unable to automatically download and install the requested version. This JRE must be installed manually."

what changes are required in the JNLP file to auto download and install a required JRE 1.7 version on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "flag as duplicate" function, no matter what subset of the target title I enter in the search box, does not offer the following question, here it is as answer:

See [Java Web Start is unable to automatically download and install the requested version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079626/java-web-start-is-unable-to-automatically-download-and-install-the-requested-ver).

In my personal view however, leaving it to the Java runtime to "upgrade" itself on demand feels risky. The Java deployment toolkit (which I think would be involved) has been found to be vulnerable more than once. I would prefer requiring admins or users to manually install the required JRE version.